# Proving the uncountability of sets for the Entrance Exam Problem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-set-theory

I am working on entrance exam problem, wherein I aim to demonstrate that the following sets constitute uncountable sets.

> (A) The set of all $2\times 2$ real matrices with rational eigenvalues.
>
> (B) The set of all real matrices whose row echelon form has rational
> entries

**My attempt:** Set A is uncountable. For instance if I consider an upper triangular matrix of the form (1 a;
0 0) where $a$ is real, even though its roots are rational, due to presence of one real entry, the matrix itself becomes uncountable when I view its elements as a set ((1, a), (0, 0)).

Set B is uncountable. For instance if I consider a matrix of the form (a  a; a a), where $a$ is real, even though its row echelon form ( 1 1; 0 0) has rational entries, the matrix itself becomes uncountable due to presence of $a$ in the matrix.

Am I on the right track? Is there any alternative better approach to solve this question?
Thank you so much

Comment: Your solution is fine and simple.  Is the row echelon form in B equal $ (1,1;0,0)$ ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks for the comment sir. I have to edit my answer related to Echelon form

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I have edited my answer. Could you please check?

Comment: You have the right idea but saying "the matrix is uncountable" is nonsensical.  The *set of matrices of that form* is uncountable.

Comment: Looks nearly perfect. At two places you should replace "the matrix is uncountable"  by "the set of such matrices is uncountable". See the comment by @MW One matrix of that form  constitutes a set consisting of just one element.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarcThank you so much

Comment: @MW Thank you for the valuable suggestions